# Where does windows 8.1 virtual machine occupy disk space in linux

Tags: virtual-machine, disk-usage, vmware

I want to have a Windows 8.1 32-bits virtual machine on my Ubuntu distribution. I'd mainly use it to play the videogame "Roblox". It seems like windows 8.1 would take around 12GB of disk space, plus some extra space for programs which I'd like it to be around 20GB.

In what filesystem from my Ubuntu distribution would that disk space be required? Is it `/home`, is it `/`? Or could it be on my 613GB "data" partition?

```
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           789M  9,6M  779M   2% /run
/dev/sda8        46G   43G  1,1G  98% /
tmpfs           3,9G  202M  3,7G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda9       145G  101G   37G  74% /home
/dev/sda1       496M   57M  440M  12% /boot/efi
tmpfs           789M   68K  789M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda4       613G  369G  213G  64% /media/user/data
```

Comment: Choose a partition, it's your choice.

Comment: you would probably use an image file to store the win8 installation and act as win8's virtual drive (file extensions like `.vhd`, `.vdi`, `.qcow`).  you can store these files whereever you like.  some virtualization technologies might allow using an actual partition, but it's not recommended due to the potential for problems.

Comment: A virtual machine is a bunch of ordinary files. You put them wherever you want. It's like asking where does a text editor put the text files.

Comment: Without   intervention in $HOME from the user who installs windows 8.1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chose the location of virtual disk image file.

If you use `qemu-kvm` along `Virtual Machine Manager` GUI tool to create your new virtual machine you'll get option to create/chose a disk image for new virtual machine. There are command line option also for the same.

If you use Oracle's `VirtualBox` again you'll have option to chose disk image location.

So, it's all depends on you where you want to keep the virtual hard disk file. If you proceeds with all default options it'll be somewhere inside `/home/username/somefolder/`